# What is the amount of possibilities for the following case?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation, sampling

Suppose I have 24 variables. There is exactly one possible composition of these variables. Now I subtract one variable (can be each one) which gives me 24 possible compositions of the data (the order of the variables does not matter). Again, I subtract one variable etc...

What is the sum of possibilites I am left with, if I were to repeat this step until there are none left?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:As an example: I have 3 variables - A, B and C. There is exactly one possible composition of the dataset: A B C. If I subtract one I can end up with A and B, A and C and B and C. So I have 3 possible compositions of the dataset.

Comment: "Compositions of variables"? Are about probabilistic variables? Also, could you please provide an example of what you mean, and tell us what you think the solution it, what you expect...?

Comment: Edited the post.